# Watir - working with CSS elements

Tags: css, ruby, cucumber, watir, gherkin

Hopefully someone can help me, either by telling me it cant be done or pointing me in the right direction.

I am trying to use Watir Ruby written tests to check a CSS element is being applied to my page when a check box is checked. 
I can check the checkbox attribute fine and see that it is checked, but a differnt test i have to perform is to check that the image has been highlighted after the checking the checkbox.

Currently i have not been able to find anything useful around after a couple of hours of searching. Has anyone come across a problem liek this you ahve had to overcome, and if so how did you go about it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

If you're using vanilla Watir (meaning IE browser on Windows) then it is also possible to get style of the element from win32ole object:

```
irb(main):001:0> require "watir"
=> true
irb(main):002:0> b = Watir::Browser.new
=> #<Watir::IE:0x4bce118 url="about:blank" title="">
irb(main):003:0> b.goto "google.com"
=> 2.298132
irb(main):004:0> i = b.image(:alt => "Google")
=> #<Watir::Image:0x433fa28 located=false how={:alt=>"Google"} what=nil>
irb(main):005:0> i.style
=> #<WIN32OLE:0x431ca90>
irb(main):008:0> i.style.paddingTop
=> "26px"
```

This #style method also returns computed style, e.g. styles from CSS and not just from style tag.

You can check out all the possible style ole methods from msdn at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535870(v=vs.85).aspx under styles properties.

Answer (score 1):

How do you apply the CSS element to image after checking the checkbox? If you add the class attribute for highlighting, I guess checking class attribute is the simplest way.

for example

```
browser.image.class_name =~ /foobar/
```

If using style attribute, I think you might need to check HTML itself, like

```
browser.image.html =~ /style=\"?foobar\"?/
```